# Expo/React Native Background/Sleep Mode Timer

Tags: react-native, timer, expo, background-task

I'm currently trying to get a **timer** to work in Expo/React Native. I want that my timer is still running in the background when the user for example locks his phone screen or he just puts the app in the background. Is this somehow manageable with react native?

I need this functionality to send a notification when the timer is finished, even when it's in background as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, background timer stops about an hour after phone idle. location can't really do background timer as its background services is only triggered when other apps are actively requestion location such as google maps.

Comment: So there is no possibility to achieve my request?